# How to synchronize Bigquery and Oracle Database with/without Dataflow?

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I tried to use Dataflow [template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#jdbctobigquery).

I realized that it is a batch process and not a stream. This template does not make Bigquery sync with Oracle database, rather just copy the data and paste it.

I tried to run the same job periodically but the duplicate data is added to Bigquery. I saw some third party solution to do the same but I would like to use first party solution as much as possible.

Is it possible to make Bigquery synchronize with oracle database?

Comment: I will look into this and confirm if this is possible. It may be possible to modify the template here to use streaming mode, by periodically processing a window of data over time.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/JdbcToBigQuery.java

If its not possible to create a template this way, you may be able to run the streaming pipeline from code instead, and leave the streaming pipeline running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a source that reads changes from an Oracle database. Unfortunately current Beam JDBC source cannot serve this purpose, so you'll probably have to develop a new source for this.